# Node js How to make changes to an exported module so it will be shown in other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I am following a course for a Node js ( among other things ) , in this course passport.js is used. In index.js file i required the configuration module that we created for passport.js to use "Google Strategy" , and in my routes i required the global instance for passport.js and i used it to authenticate user via oauth of google .
my question is how the passport code in my routes knows that i am using google strategy and their configs like ClientID and ClientSecret even if i am not using the same instance of passport.js in my config file , to make things clear here is the code :

**Index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
require("./services/passport");


const app = express();

require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);

app.listen(5000);
```

**passport.js** inside my **services folder**

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const keys = require("../config/keys");

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log("accessToken", accessToken);
      console.log("refreshToken", refreshToken);
      console.log("profile", profile);
      console.log("done", done);
    }
  )
);
```

**authRoute.js**

```
const passport = require("passport");
// here i am importing the global passport , how this instance knows that i used google strategy
// in my configs and their configs like googleClientID ...ect ?

module.exports = (app) => {

  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      scope: ["profile", "email"],
    })
  );

  app.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google"));
};
```

Comment: The passport module exports an [instance of Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/index.js#L13) as the default object. This object holds contains state and that state is the same one between require statements.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule so if i want to create my own module that apply this technique all i need is exporting instance of the class instead of exporting the class itself ?

Comment: That's correct.